# Using variables from packages that weren't loaded yet

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to bind keys in keymaps from packages that are not loaded yet, due to the lazy loading of Doom Emacs I suppose(?):

```lisp
  (pcase-dolist (`(,package ,keymap) '((eww eww-mode-map)
                                       (info Info-mode-map)
                                       (man Man-mode-map)
                                       (nov nov-mode-map)
                                       (devdocs devdeocs-mode-map)))
    (eval-after-load package
      (evil-define-key* 'normal keymap "j" #'my/pixel-scroll-down)))
```

The problem is that I'm unsure how to unquote it once we're inside `eval-after-load`. `eval` seems to eagerly evaluate it when I run the expression rather than when the package is loaded.

How can I programmatically use a variable only when it's loaded?

Answer (score 0):

`eval-after-load` is a Lisp **function** and therefore its arguments are evaluated before the function is executed.

So your `(evil-define-key* ...)` is evaluated at the time you call `eval-after-load`, and the resulting return value is evaluated after something is loaded.

You want to quote the FORM argument, in other words.